# Quotes in dual quoting delimiters

Tags: python, string

I read the official manual and find these examples.

1. ```
   '"Isn\'t," she said.'
   ```

   and if I change the `\'` to `'`

   ```
   '"Isn't," she said.'
   ```

   python will tell you that's invalid syntax.

   But if I change the `'` to `"`

   ```
   '"Isn"t," she said.'
   ```

   It prints without error.

   What I think is the inside the `" "`, the `'` will be seen as a character, but why does python tell me there is a syntax error?
2. And if I change it to

   ```
   '''"Isn't," she said.'''
   ```

   it prints normally. What is the difference between

   ```
   '''"Isn't," she said.'''
   ```

   and

   ```
   '"Isn't," she said.'
   ```

   ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Everything* from the first `'` single quote is a string, including the double quotes. It doesn't matter how many double quotes you use within a single-quoted string. The string ends at the *next* single quote encountered, which is why you have to escape any literal single quotes within the literal.

In your second example you use a *triple quoted* string. Python then regards everything up to the next triple quote (`'''`) part of the string literal.

Python accept 4 different forms of quoting to delimit a literal string:

```
'single quotes'
"double quotes"
'''tripled single quotes'''
"""tripled double quotes"""
```

Note that when you use tripled quotes, newlines can be used:

```
"""Line one
line two
line three"""
```

You cannot do that with single quoted strings.

Comment: @kindall: Thanks for the correction; not being a native speaker there are a few spelling mistakes that keep coming back to haunt me. :-)

Comment: No problem. I only fixed it because it kept reminding me of beer (trippel).  :-)

Comment: @kindall: Which points quite accusingly to my language roots. :-) I could go some Grimbergen or Westmalle *right now*..

Comment: I love Belgian beers. It was that style that got me into beer. My wife loves the farmhouse style like Saison Dupont. Hmm, I feel a visit to [Brouwer's](http://seattlebeernews.com/2011/02/seattle-beer-news-top-10-beer-spots-2-brouwers-cafe/) coming on...

Comment: [This is roughly](http://www.europeanbeerguide.net/zholpubs.htm#alphen) what I grew up with; I'll be visiting the ole homeland soon, I'll catch up then..